# What is the difference between ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and request.getContextPath()

Tags: java, jsp

So I have a .jsp that displays the header part of my web application.  This is a very standard looking page.  I have a bar at the top with things like Login, Register, Contact Us, etc...   And below that we have a horizontal navigation bar.

This is a standard Spring web application with a maven build.  It produces a file, web.war, that we deploy to tomcat.  on dev, this works fine.

We are testing production, and want this war to be the root,  so we rename the war to ROOT.war and restart.  everything fine.

Now sometimes,  we get the navigation section from a Content Management System. We set the text as a variable and display that.  No obviously we can't use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} as that wont get parsed this way,  so before we display the text we do this in the jsp

```
<%  navcopy = navcopy.replace("${pageContext.request.contextPath}", request.getContextPath()); %>
```

Now this is adding the /web to the URL.  Now this is baffling to me as registration link in the jsp works:

```
 <a id="home-left-menu-item" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register.html">Register Now!</a>
```

So hoe does ${pageContext.request.contextPath} parsed in the jsp return the correct root but the call request.getContextPath() returns "/web"

Aren't they essentially the same call to the same object to the same method?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, one is the original request URL, while the other is the last controller you hit after all the redirects. But wait for confirmation. :)

Comment: just a thought,could it be due to the difference in location of jsp and the the template relative to the project directory,where the variable is set?

Answer (score 0):

${pageContext.request.contextPath} : Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context of the request.
In fact, it is identical to request.getContextPath(), since ${pageContext.request} refers to the HttpServletRequest of the current request.

For example:

```
http://localhost:80/myProjectName/path/servlet
```

${pageContext.request.contextPath} returns /myProjectName

request.getServletPath() Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet, e.g. /path/servlet

${pageContext.request.servletPath} returns /path/servlet

**For this code try this:**

```
<a id="home-left-menu-item" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/register.html">Register Now!</a>
```

Comment: The above answer is incorrect if an application isn't running as the ROOT webapp;   Specifically, "In fact, it is identical to request.getContextPath(), since ${pageContext.request} refers to the HttpServletRequest of the current request."

Consider an application named  test.war and deployed at /test

${pageContext.request.contextPath} returns /test

${request.contextPath} returns empty string

The above examples tested on Tomcat 9